# Getting undefined reference error

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors, ld, undefined-reference

I am including a header file gps.h in my main program and calling a function of header file included Gps_Pthread().
I tried adding and removing parameter of it.

below us the code for header file

```
#ifndef __GPS_H__
#define __GPS_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define u8 unsigned char
typedef struct {
    u8 UTCDateTime[6]; //YMDHMS
    char Status[20]; //A/V
    u8 Latitude[4]; //ddmm.mmmm
    char NS[20]; //N/S
    u8 Longitude[5]; //dddmm.mmmm
    char EW[20]; //E/W
    u8 Speed[3]; //speed000.0~999.9kts
    u8 Course[3]; //course000.0~359.9degree
} stru_GPSRMC;

typedef struct {
    char UTCTime[20]; //HMS
    char Status[20]; //A/V
    char Latitude[20]; //ddmm.mmmm
    char NS[20]; //N/S
    char Longitude[20]; //dddmm.mmmm
    char EW[20]; //E/W
    char Speed[20]; //speed000.0~999.9kts
    char Course[20]; //course000.0~359.9degree
    char UTCDate[20];//YMD

} strubf_GPSRMC;

typedef struct {
    char UTCTime[20]; //HMS
    char Latitude[20]; //ddmm.mmmm
    char NS[20]; //N/S
    char Longitude[20]; //dddmm.mmmm
    char EW[20]; //E/W
    char PositionFix[20];
    char SatUsed[20];
} strubf_GPSGGA;

typedef struct {
    u8 UTCTime[3];    //hhmmss.mmm
    u8 Latitude[4];    //ddmm.mmmm
    char NS[20];        //N/S
    u8 Longitude[5];    //dddmm.mmmm
    char EW[20];        //E/W
    u8 PositionFix;    //0,1,2,6
    u8 SatUsed;    //00~12
//    u8 HDOP[4];        //0.5~99.9
    //   u8 Altitude[7];    //-9999.9~99999.9
} stru_GPSGGA;

typedef struct {
    u8 Mode;        //A/M
    u8 Mode2;    //0,1,2,3
    u8 SatUsedList[12];
    u8 PDOP[4];
    u8 HDOP[4];
    u8 VDOP[4];
} stru_GPSGSA;

typedef struct {
    u8 SatID;
//    u8 Elevation[2];//0-90 degree
//    u8 Azimuth[3]; //0-359 degree
    u8 SNR; //0-99 dbHz
} stru_SatInfo;

typedef struct {
    u8 SatInView;
    stru_SatInfo SatInfo[12];
} stru_GPSGSV;

#define NMEA_NULL    0x00            //GPS statement type
#define NMEA_GPGGA    0x01
#define NMEA_GPGSA    0x02
#define NMEA_GPGSV    0x04
#define NMEA_GPRMC    0x08

extern stru_GPSRMC GPS_RMC_Data;
extern stru_GPSGGA GPS_GGA_Data;
extern stru_GPSGSA GPS_GSA_Data;
extern stru_GPSGSV GPS_GSV_Data;
extern strubf_GPSRMC GPSBF_RMC_DATA;
extern strubf_GPSGGA GPSBF_GGA_DATA;
extern unsigned char buffer0[200];


void ShowGPSTime(void);

void ParserGPGGA(void);

void ParserGPRMC(void);

extern void *Gps_Pthread(void *args);

extern void *sendGps_Pthread(void *args);

#endif
```

when sending parameter in function sendGps_Pthread() I get

> undefined reference to `Gps_Pthread'

and when i call it without parameter then the error is

> too few arguments to function 'Gps_Pthread'

How do i call that function to initialise the gps and get location?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compiling needs the header file. Linking needs the binary object (library).

Comment: `__GPS_H__` is a reserved identifier.

Comment: The `undefined reference` error is printed when your application is linked, and is complaining that the function does not exist (here you only show the prototype for the function, not the function body itself). Do you have the `Gps_Pthread()` source compiled in to your application?

Comment: C isn't Java. `#include`  isn't `import`.

Comment: added #include now

Comment: @Attie I have a c file for it also

Comment: Did you compile and link that C file into your application / executable?

Comment: @Attie yes i created .so file from c file and added it in make file also LIBS   = -lpthread -l1306pos -hello -lz in this hello is the gps.c file lib

Comment: Should be `-lhello` then.